# Custom workflows in Cadence or Temporal

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

I am planning to use Cadence or Temporal Workflow for the architecture, however we plan to give the users a lot of power in deciding the workflow. Both Cadence and Temporal mention in their Use Cases that Custom DSL are supported by their SDK, but I couldn't see that feature. Will you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, custom DSLs can be implemented on top of Cadence/Temporal with a relative ease. The basic idea is that Temporal workflow definition is code and you have to write a simple interpreter of the DSL using that code. As code is fault tolerant and durable the DSL will get all the benefits of Cadence / Temporal.

[Here is a DSL sample using Go SDK](https://github.com/temporalio/temporal-go-samples/tree/master/dsl). We are going to add the Java one later.